# How to make assertion for below body request via Cypress. Thanks

Tags: javascript, json, post, cypress

I need to test the properties that I have in the below JSON by using Cypress. I think I have a problem with reaching to each property and verify them.

```js
describe('POST method', () => {
    it('get a list of faceted aggregations', () => {

        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url:"host+endpoints",

            headers:{
                "Authorization":"xxxxxxx",
                "content-type": "application/json"
            },

            body: {
                "search": {
                  "auctionType": [
                    "basic_auction"
                  
                  ],
                  "statuses": [
                    "ongoing"
                  ],
                  "sites": [
                    "autobid.de"
                  ],
                  "urls": [
                    "yyyyyyy"
                  ],
                  "ahIds": [
                    53825-62-2014918
                  ],
                  "biddingPlatforms": [
                    "aaaaaaa"
                  ],
                  "winningPlatforms": [
                    "aaaaa"
                  ],
                  "losingPlatforms": [
                    "aaaaaa"
                  ],
                  "hasBids": true,
                  "hasVat": true,
                  "query": "string",
                  "range": [
                    {
                      "auctionEndDatetime": {
                        "min": "string",
                        "max": "string"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "auctionEndDatetime": {
                        "min": "string",
                        "max": "string"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "auctionStartDatetime": {
                        "min": "string",
                        "max": "string"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "createdDatetime": {
                        "min": "string",
                        "max": "string"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "updatedDatetime": {
                        "min": "string",
                        "max": "string"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "price": {
                        "min": "string",
                        "max": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "exists": [
                    "string"
                  ],
                  "filters": {
                    "vehicles": [
                      {
                        "brand": "string",
                        "modelIds": 0,
                        "model": "string"
                      }
                  
               
                  }
                }
```

My Response Body:

```json
{"data": {
    "count": 252655,
    "aggregations": {
        "filters.bodyTypes": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "Station wagon",
                    "doc_count": 45778
                },
                {
                    "key": "SUV",
                    "doc_count": 30188
                },
                {
                    "key": "Hatchback",
                    "doc_count": 25059
                },
                {
                    "key": "Saloon",
                    "doc_count": 13636
                },
                {
                    "key": "Van",
                    "doc_count": 11266
                },
                {
                    "key": "MPV",
                    "doc_count": 10158
                },
                {
                    "key": "Estate",
                    "doc_count": 9700
                },
                {
                    "key": "Estate, Number of doors 5",
                    "doc_count": 6800
                },
                {
                    "key": "Berline avec hayon",
                    "doc_count": 6276
                },
                {
                    "key": "Saloon, Number of doors 5",
                    "doc_count": 5238
                },
                {
                    "key": "berline hayon - VP",
                    "doc_count": 3298
                },
                {
                    "key": "All-terrain vehicle, Number of doors 5, All-wheel drive",
                    "doc_count": 2783
                },
                {
                    "key": "Stationwagon",
                    "doc_count": 2727
                },
                {
                    "key": "Saloon, Number of doors 4",
                    "doc_count": 2466
                },
                {
                    "key": "",
                    "doc_count": 2270
                },
                {
                    "key": "Van / minibus, Number of doors 5",
                    "doc_count": 2058
                },
                {
                    "key": "Other",
                    "doc_count": 1989
                },
                {
                    "key": "Berlina",
                    "doc_count": 1901
                },
                {
                    "key": "H",
                    "doc_count": 1867
                },
                {
                    "key": "Crossover",
                    "doc_count": 1860
                },
                {
                    "key": "Panel van",
                    "doc_count": 1833
                },
                {
                    "key": "HA -BERLINA CON PORTON",
                    "doc_count": 1796
                },
                {
                    "key": "SUV VP - VP",
                    "doc_count": 1771
                },
                {
                    "key": "Estate, Number of doors 5, All-wheel drive",
                    "doc_count": 1760
                },
                {
                    "key": "Higher Mid-Range Cars",
                    "doc_count": 1748
                },
                {
                    "key": "Station Wagon",
                    "doc_count": 1673
                },
                {
                    "key": "Monovolume",
                    "doc_count": 1603
                },
                {
                    "key": "Saloon, Number of doors 3",
                    "doc_count": 1547
                },
                {
                    "key": "W",
                    "doc_count": 1513
                },
                {
                    "key": "Mid-range Cars",
                    "doc_count": 1492
                },
                {
                    "key": "All-terrain vehicle, Number of doors 5",
                    "doc_count": 1453
                },
                {
                    "key": "Wagon",
                    "doc_count": 1210
                },
                {
                    "key": "break - VP",
                    "doc_count": 1201
                },
                {
                    "key": "ES -FAMILIAR",
                    "doc_count": 1158
                },
                {
                    "key": "SW",
                    "doc_count": 1064
                },
                {
                    "key": "Berline 5 portes",
                    "doc_count": 1017
                },
                {
                    "key": "Personal car",
                    "doc_count": 994
                },
                {
                    "key": "Sedan",
                    "doc_count": 994
                },
                {
                    "key": "SUV Medium",
                    "doc_count": 949
                },
                {
                    "key": "SUV4x2",
                    "doc_count": 946
                },
                {
                    "key": "berline VU - VS",
                    "doc_count": 938
                },
                {
                    "key": "F",
                    "doc_count": 896
                },
                {
                    "key": "Convertible / Roadster, Number of doors 2",
                    "doc_count": 894
                },
                {
                    "key": "CI",
                    "doc_count": 867
                },
                {
                    "key": "Stationwagen",
                    "doc_count": 835
                },
                {
                    "key": "Monovolume 4x4",
                    "doc_count": 805
                },
                {
                    "key": "mini MS - VP",
                    "doc_count": 802
                },
                {
                    "key": "Light duty truck, Number of doors 4",
                    "doc_count": 738
                },
                {
                    "key": "BREAK",
                    "doc_count": 717
                },
                {
                    "key": "Mixed car",
                    "doc_count": 702
                },
                {
                    "key": "VU1",
                    "doc_count": 677
                },
                {
                    "key": "M",
                    "doc_count": 673
                },
                {
                    "key": "Coupe",
                    "doc_count": 665
                },
                {
                    "key": "MONO-M",
                    "doc_count": 655
                },
                {
                    "key": "Saloon, Number of doors 4, All-wheel drive",
                    "doc_count": 634
                },
                {
                    "key": "Mini MPV",
                    "doc_count": 588
                },
                {
                    "key": "crossover - VP",
                    "doc_count": 584
                },
                {
                    "key": "OD -TODOTERRENO",
                    "doc_count": 536
                },
                {
                    "key": "CV -FURGON DERIVADO DE TURISMO",
                    "doc_count": 530
                },
                {
                    "key": "Compact cars",
                    "doc_count": 529
                },
                {
                    "key": "4x4",
                    "doc_count": 527
                },
                {
                    "key": "fourgonnette - VU",
                    "doc_count": 524
                },
                {
                    "key": "Estate, Number of doors 4",
                    "doc_count": 511
                },
                {
                    "key": "Break VP",
                    "doc_count": 504
                },
                {
                    "key": "Coupé",
                    "doc_count": 503
                },
                {
                    "key": "Kombi",
                    "doc_count": 490
                },
                {
                    "key": "Saloon, Number of doors 5, All-wheel drive",
                    "doc_count": 481
                },
                {
                    "key": "Fourgonnette",
                    "doc_count": 454
                },
                {
                    "key": "Berline VU 5 portes",
                    "doc_count": 452
                },
                {
                    "key": "KOM",
                    "doc_count": 437
                },
                {
                    "key": "S",
                    "doc_count": 427
                },
                {
                    "key": "Sports car / Coupé, Number of doors 2",
                    "doc_count": 426
                },
                {
                    "key": "coupe - VP",
                    "doc_count": 426
                },
                {
                    "key": "SA -SEDAN",
                    "doc_count": 414
                },
                {
                    "key": "MM -MONOVOLUMEN COMPACTO",
                    "doc_count": 413
                },
                {
                    "key": "Light duty truck",
                    "doc_count": 390
                },
                {
                    "key": "Fourgon lourd",
                    "doc_count": 384
                },
                {
                    "key": "SUV 4x4",
                    "doc_count": 382
                },
                {
                    "key": "Furgon largo",
                    "doc_count": 356
                },
                {
                    "key": "MONO-S",
                    "doc_count": 352
                },
                {
                    "key": "businessclass Cars",
                    "doc_count": 352
                },
                {
                    "key": "berline - VP",
                    "doc_count": 349
                },
                {
                    "key": "Mini monospace",
                    "doc_count": 332
                },
                {
                    "key": "Minivan",
                    "doc_count": 326
                },
                {
                    "key": "fourgon tôle - VU",
                    "doc_count": 319
                },
                {
                    "key": "Van / minibus, Number of doors 4",
                    "doc_count": 315
                },
                {
                    "key": "Fourgon leger",
                    "doc_count": 307
                },
                {
                    "key": "Kasten",
                    "doc_count": 284
                },
                {
                    "key": "Convertible",
                    "doc_count": 266
                },
                {
                    "key": "MPV (multi-purpose vehicle)",
                    "doc_count": 252
                     }
                ]
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I made a change base on Mihi's comment.

```
describe('POST method', () => {
    it('get a list of faceted aggregations', () => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url:"host + endpoint",

            headers:{
                "Authorization":"xxxx",
                "content-type": "application/json"
            },

            body: {  
                "search": {
                  "auctionType": [
                    "basic_auction"     
                  ],
                  "statuses": [
                    "ongoing"
                  ],
                  "sites": [
                    "autobid.de"
                  ],
                  "urls": [
                    "https://autobid.de?action=car&show=details&id=2014918&L=1"
                  ]
                }
},

            failOnStatusCode: false

            
        })
            .then((res) => {

              return response.body.data.aggregations['filters.bodyTypes'].buckets
})
            .then(bodyTypeObjects => {

            expect(bodyTypeObjects.length).to.eq(90)

          const bodyTypeCounts = bodyTypeObjects.reduce((acc, bodyTypeObject) => {
            acc[bodyTypeObject.key] = bodyTypeObject.doc_count
    return acc
  }, {})
  return bodyTypeCounts
})
.then(bodyTypeCounts => {
  expect(res.status).to.eq(200)

  expect(bodyTypeCounts).to.have.property('Station Wagon')
  expect(bodyTypeCounts['Station Wagon']).to.be.gt(1000)
```

And my error after running is like below:

```
request POST 200 https:xxxx
2 then function(){}
ReferenceError
response is not defined
cypress/integration/specs/API-Testing/auctionAggregations.spec.js:41:15
  39 |             .then((res) => {
  40 | 
> 41 |               return response.body.data.aggregations['filters.bodyTypes'].buckets
     |               ^
  42 | })
  43 | .then(bodyTypeObjects => {
  44 |
```

Comment: Do you want to assert the entire response body against a sample response json that you have?

Comment: I want to assert each proporty

Answer (score 3):

For me, it is better to transform the big json before testing.

The response has this nesting

```js
{
  data: {
    count: 252655,
    aggregations: {
      "filters.bodyTypes": {
         doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0,
         sum_other_doc_count: 0,
         buckets: [
           {
             key: "Station wagon",
             doc_count: 45778,
           },
```

but that makes the test code harder to figure out.

Start by pulling out the aggregations with this function

```js
(response) => {
  return response.body.data.aggregations['filters.bodyTypes'].buckets
}
```

You can then check things like the number of bodyTypes

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  ...
})
.then(response => {
  return response.body.data.aggregations['filters.bodyTypes'].buckets
})
.then(bodyTypeObjects => {
  expect(bodyTypeObjects.length).to.eq(90)
})
```

To check individual items, you need to deconstruct the bodyTypeObjects, e.g

```js
const match = Cypress._.filter(bodyTypeObjects, Cypress._.matches({key: 'Station Wagon'}))
expect(match).to.have.length(1)
```

but to make the test code simpler, do another transform from this shape

```js
[{key: 'Station wagon', doc_count: 45778}, {key: 'SUV', doc_count: 30188}, ...]
```

to this shape

```js
{ Station wagon: 45778, SUV: 30188, ... }
```

Then the tests become a lot simpler

**Full test**

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  ...
})
.then(response => {
  return response.body.data.aggregations['filters.bodyTypes'].buckets
})
.then(bodyTypeObjects => {

  expect(bodyTypeObjects.length).to.eq(90)

  const bodyTypeCounts = bodyTypeObjects.reduce((acc, bodyTypeObject) => {
    acc[bodyTypeObject.key] = bodyTypeObject.doc_count
    return acc
  }, {})
  return bodyTypeCounts
})
.then(bodyTypeCounts => {

  expect(bodyTypeCounts).to.have.property('Station Wagon')
  expect(bodyTypeCounts['Station Wagon']).to.be.gt(1000)

  // OR

  cy.wrap(bodyTypeCounts)
    .should('have.property', 'Station Wagon', 1673)

})
```

Comment: Thank you soo much @Mihi for your answer. I tried the method that you mentioned. I got this error:

1 request POST 200 "url"
2 then. function(){}
*ReferenceError*
*response is not defined*
  39 |             .then((res) => {
  40 | 
> 41 |               return response.body.data.aggregations['filters.bodyTypes'].buckets
     |               ^
  42 | })
  43 | .then(bodyTypeObjects => {
  44 |

Comment: Hard to tell from that comment, but looks like you mismatched the response variable name (called it `res`) but used it as `response`. First time doing javascript?

Comment: You can add to the bottom of your question for clarity.

Comment: I added into my question box

Comment: Thanks for the addition. Just change `.then((res) => ` to `.then((response) => `

Answer (score 1):

**Response validation by fixture**

This was previously shown, but has since been remove.

For completeness, I'll add it here

```js
cy.fixture('faceted-aggregations-response.json').then(expectedResponse => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url:"host+endpoints",
    ...
  }).then(response => {

    // use deep.eq to check all nested sub-properties
    expect(response).to.deep.eq(expectedResponse)

  })
})
```

If the order of aggregations can change each time, you will need to install an additional package

```js
yarn add deep-equal-in-any-order
```

**Test**

```js
const deepEqualInAnyOrder = require('deep-equal-in-any-order');
chai.use(deepEqualInAnyOrder);

cy.fixture('faceted-aggregations-response.json').then(expectedResponse => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url:"host+endpoints",
    ...
  }).then(response => {

    expect(response).to.deep.equalInAnyOrder(expectedResponse)

  })
})
```